# UIProgressBar with streaming and Playing progress

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

Hai all,

in my audio streaming application i like to show the progress of downloading and playing, when i tried it with MPMoviePlayerController, it shows both progress in the same progress bar, is there any way to implement (or use) the applies default progress bar in our application ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two overlapping progress bars, one being a little transparent. This way, you create the illusion of the same progress bar showing two things independently. The semi-transparent one should be on top, so you can see it.

Answer (score 1):

You have three options:

1. Implement it yourself. This may be difficult, you may have to rewrite the entire progress bar.
2. Use class-dump, reverse engineering, and lots of time to find out what undocumented class they use -- then get rejected from the store for that :/.
3. Give up, and just find an alternative way to display the info (two UIProgressBars?).